# IntelliJ - "SnapShooter listening on port XXXXX"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am attempting to run a Java program and all of a sudden, whenever I run it I get a message like "SnapShooter listening on port 40182" at the beginning of the standard output stream. The code runs fine, it's just that the message always appears. What is SnapShooter? Is it some sort of malware?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not malware; malware typically does not announce its presence via a message to your standard output. SnapShooter it's a component that is used to capture snapshots of Swing UI forms in the application you run from the IDE. The message is displayed because you checked the "Enable capturing form snapshots" checkbox in your run configuration settings, and will go away if you uncheck it.